# jq trying to iterate over two sets of values

Tags: json, jq

Update:  I have experimented with extracting the paths I desire to update and using those paths relative to the local and returned objects (read below) in a setpath(paths;getpath(paths)) construction.  I can now iterate over the $paths array and make the desired updates to the local json object.

Using the thermostats2.json file below and a ret.json that differs from thermostats2.json only in:

{"location":{"livingroom":{"setpoints":{"day":"25000"}}}} #vs{"day":"23000"}

my script now looks like:

```
. as $obj |

# obtain location keys from $obj as they may have changed locally prior to $retobj being processed

($obj.location | keys? ) as $locs |

# setpoints are fixed in this code as ["day","night","away"]

["day","night","away"] as $setpoints |

[path($obj.location[($locs[])].setpoints[($setpoints[])])] as $paths |

reduce
  range(0; $paths|length) as $i
(.; . | setpath($paths[$i];( $retobj[0] | getpath($paths[$i])))  ) | .
```

I don't need the $obj variable at this time but I have not cleaned that up yet.  Please comment if you see problems with this approach or if this looks like a good solution.  I will answer this question if the comments indicate it should be.

I have a json object that contains several location objects each, in turn, containing several setpoint objects, among other data.  A remote application is provided this json object and returns updates to the values of the setpoint objects, if required.  I would like to update the local json object rather than replace it with the returned object.

I do not want to assume the returned object's location keys are identical to those of the local object as the local object may have been maintained while the remote object was being modified.

I have figured out how to extract the location keys from the local file and create an array containing the setpoint keys whose values I am interested in updating.  I have also been able to figure out how to reduce the updated values from the returned object into an array.

What I have not figured out is how to iterate over the locations and the setpoints together in order to update the values in the local json object.

I invoke jq with:

```
# usage : jq --slurpfile retobj ret.json --from-file query.jq thermostats2.json

query.jq contains:
# use $obj as the local object to be updated with values returned in $retobj
# $retobj is not permitted to modify the structure of $obj

. as $obj |

# obtain location keys from $obj as they may have changed locally prior to $retobj being processed

($obj.location | keys? ) as $locs |

# setpoints are fixed in this code as ["day","night","away"]

["day","night","away"] as $setpoints |
reduce $retobj[0].location[($locs[])].setpoints[($setpoints[])] as $item
( []; . + [$item] )
 | . as $vals |
$vals
```

thermostats2.json:

```
{ "mode":"Home",
  "location": {
    "livingroom": {
    "scale":"Celcius",
    "current": {
        "valid":"YES",
        "reading":"23000",
        "time":"000000"
    },
    "previous": {
        "reading":"23000",
        "time":"000000"
    },
    "setpoints": {
        "schedule": {
        "weekday": {"day":"0600",
                "night":"2100"
               },
        "weekend": {"day":"0630",
                "night":"2200"
               }
        },
        "active":"day",
        "day":"23000",
        "night":"15556",
        "away":"12778"
    }
    },
    "familyroom": {
    "scale":"Celcius",
    "current": {
        "valid":"YES",
        "reading":"23000",
        "time":"000000"
    },
    "previous": {
        "reading":"23000",
        "time":"000000"
    },
    "setpoints": {
        "schedule": {
        "weekday": {"day":"0600",
                "night":"2100"
               },
        "weekend": {"day":"0630",
                "night":"2200"
               }

        },
        "active":"day",
        "day":"23000",
        "night":"15556",
        "away":"12778"
    }
    },
    "28-000005e2fdef": {
    "scale":"Celcius",
    "current": {
        "valid":"YES",
        "reading":"23000",
        "time":"000000"
    },
    "previous": {
        "reading":"23000",
        "time":"000000"
    },
    "setpoints": {
        "schedule": {
        "weekday": {"day":"0600",
                "night":"2100"
               },
        "weekend": {"day":"0630",
                "night":"2200"
               }
        },
        "active":"day",
        "day":"23000",
        "night":"15556",
        "away":"12778"
    }
    }
  }
}
```

What I cannot find is any means to set the values for the same objects in $obj, i.e. effectively:

$obj[0].location[($locs[])].setpoints[($setpoints[])] = $vals

I understand that, as a novice, I am not likely choosing the preferred approach for solving this type of problem.  I am also struggling with embracing the filter paradigm in some of the built-in functions, particularly foreach.

to recap my goal, I wish to:

get the proper object values in $retobj via location keys derived from the local obj and the setpoint keys defined in the filter, and set the same paths in local object to those values.

Comment: 1. Where is ret.json?  2. Would it be possible to winnow the example down to something closer to being minimal, so that you can also easily show the expected output?  See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: At present ret.json is exactly the same as thermostats2.json except for {location:{livingroom:{setpoints:{day:25000}}}}     I will attempt to work on a simpler set of objects once I finish exploring an approach using path() getpath(paths) and setpath(paths;value).  I have been successful at constructing an array of paths to use for updating and applying an element of that array both to the obj and retobj.  I will edit my question one I have a bit more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my understanding of the question, I believe that using --argfile rather than --slurpfile would simplify things.

The following filter will adjust $retobj based on the contents of  thermostats2.json:

```
. as $in
| reduce ["location",
          (.location | keys[]),
          "setpoints",
          ["day","night","away"][]] as $path
    ( $retobj;
      setpath( $path; ($in | getpath($path)) ) )
```

Invocation:
    jq --argfile retobj ret.json -f query.jq thermostats2.json

Comment: Thanks.  Other than reversing the goal of modifying the contents of thermostats2.json based on $retobj, your answer confirms the approach I was exploring last night and, additionally, sheds light on an alternative notation for constructing $path that I had been slow to understand.  I will also review --argfile vs. --slurpfile to understand when to use either.  Though I have worked with jq only for a few days I am impressed by the compactness of the expressions.  Wow, what a learning curve, though!

Comment: Just looked at the Documentation for --argfile: "Do not use. Use --slurpfile instead."

Comment: --argfile has been around longer than --slurpfile and in the present case makes things easier in the sense that if you use --slurpfile then you'll have to remember to "unslurp" what has just been "slurped".